# Efficient way to fix Gradle error “Attribute ”xxx“ has already been defined” in Android Studio?

Tags: android, gradle, attributes, android-studio, duplicates

In my project, i have a module **abc**:

```
//abc module (lib) dependency
dependencies {
     compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:21.0.3'
}
```

And my app's dependency:

```
dependencies {
      compile project(':abc')
}
```

And the errors are:

```
“Attribute ”mnp“ has already been defined”
“Attribute ”xyz“ has already been defined”
...
```

And i found that all these attributes are defined in `declare-styleable` of module **abc** and **they are quite a lot**. I dont know where they produce the duplicate since i can run normally from Eclipse, not Android Studio. Some suggests that to manually rename the attributes of those but I think it is time consuming.

Any better solution? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This happens to me as well when I import project from Eclipse. Android Studio seems to binds library project even thou there was an error adding library modules.

I can usually fix this by firstly delete library modules, then opening Project's `settings.gradle` file and delete imports from there. After this, import of library modules works well.

And when I have issues with styleable file, I can usually fix this by setting SDK version to at least 20 (Android 5.0)